# Extending the Vue and ASP.NET Core (preview) template in Visual Studio with custom controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vuejs3

So I am trying to make a webpage with a Vue3.js frontend and a .NET backend. And I have used the Vue and ASP.NET Core (Preview) template in visual studio.

Everything works fine when I run it, but when I try to extend it with my own controllers I run into problems.

In the backend I have added this:
**CardController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace webapi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CardController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] names = new[]
        {
            "Forest", "Mountain", "Swamp", "Plains", "Island"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<CardController> _logger;

        public CardController(ILogger<CardController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetCard")]
        public IEnumerable<Card> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(index => new Card
            {
                Name = names[Random.Shared.Next(names.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**Card.cs**

```
namespace webapi
{
    public class Card
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And in my Vue project I have added this in the **HelleWorld.vue**

```
<template>
   ...
            <div v-if="cardPost">
                TEST
                {{ card.name }}
            </div>
     ...
</template>
export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            ...
            cardPost: null
        };
    },
    created() {
        ...
        this.fetchCard();
    ...
    methods: {
        ...
        },
        fetchCard() {
            this.cardPost = null;
            this.loading = true;

            fetch('card')
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.news = json;
                    this.loading = false;
                    return;
                });
        }
    },
});
```

Now I am very unsure what to do, I have added /card in the **vue.config.js** file

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        },
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7039/'
            },
            '^/card': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7039/'
            },
        },
        port: 5002
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
HelloWorld.vue:74 
        
        
        GET https://localhost:5002/card 404 (Not Found)
```

So my question is, how do I make this work?

Thanks for reading my question and have a lovely day